# How to implement an android delivery tracker using android studio

Tags: java, android, tracking, timeline

I want a similar progress bar tracker like shown in the pic below for an android delivery app.

See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1lB1.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Try **Timeline-View**

In XML

```
<com.github.vipulasri.timelineview.TimelineView
android:id="@+id/time_marker"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:markerSize="20dp"
app:lineSize="2dp"
app:line="@color/colorPrimary"
app:linePadding="5dp"/>
```

RecyclerView Holder

```
  public class TimeLineViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public  TimelineView mTimelineView;

    public TimeLineViewHolder(View itemView, int viewType) {
        super(itemView);
        mTimelineView = (TimelineView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_marker);
        mTimelineView.initLine(viewType);
    }
}
```

For full implementation look at [this](https://github.com/vipulasri/Timeline-View)

Comment: Thank you @Sniffer for your reply... It seems too much compicated, how can i only take the required file for my usage?

Comment: @Matyoc Post your code that would be great to help you

Comment: It is too big the comment section is not letting me post the full source code